# need help numerical triangle shell script

Tags: shell, sh

i need to write a script that looks like this

```
         6
        55
      4444
    333333
  22222222
1111111111
```

any help is appreciated :)

i tried by starting from a normal triangle but didn't know how to manage the steps above

```bash
t=6; for (( i=1; i<=6; i++));do    
    for (( k=$((6-i)); k>0; k-- )); do
        printf " "
    done

    for (( j = 1; j <= $i; j++ ));do
        printf $t
    done

    t=$((t-1))
    echo ""
done
```

the result:

```
     6
    55
   444
  3333
 22222
111111
```

my problem is that the steps from 5 to 4 is unclear to me because i need to use for loops to make lopping from +1 to +2

Comment: `for ((...))` is a ksh/bash/zsh extension, it isn't part of the POSIX sh standard -- so you should probably tag this for an extended shell instead of `sh`. Beyond that, what's the _specific technical problem_ that you're encountering? (Eyeballing it, your code looks pretty close to what you need -- I expect you're on the right track -- but you aren't telling us what goes wrong; note that [mre] requirements notate that you're expected to show _current_ output in addition to _expected_ output)

Comment: thank you i tried specify my lack of knowledge about the predicament and sorry using stack overflow for the first time not accustomed yed

Comment: Is this an extra challenge from your instructor? Your current output makes sense. But assuming this is a challenge, then adding 2 extra after 6 and 5 have completed is just a logic test when you are below the threshold number to change the line-length loop to increase by two.

Comment: You're showing desired output, but what behavior is expected to result in that output? Is it _exactly two_ top items that should be reductions of 1 rather than 2? Is it _all but the bottom three_? Something else? If you don't have a specification / don't need to be able to gracefully handle other pyramid sizes, you could just use `cat <<EOF` and hardcode your output; if you _do_ have a spec, it's necessary to know what the desired logic is before anyone can implement that logic.

Comment: Since `t` is constant (6), why do you need a loop? You just could print your triangle literally.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to get the output you want:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

maxRows=6
minCharsToPrint=1
maxCharsToPrint=2
finalMinCharsRowNr=2
maxCols=$(( maxRows * maxCharsToPrint - (finalMinCharsRowNr * minCharsToPrint) ))

indent=$maxCols
numCharsToPrint=$minCharsToPrint

for (( rowNr=1; rowNr<=maxRows; rowNr++ )); do

    if (( rowNr > finalMinCharsRowNr )); then
        numCharsToPrint=maxCharsToPrint
    fi
    indent=$(( indent - numCharsToPrint ))

    for (( colNr=1; colNr<=indent; colNr++ )); do
        printf " "
    done

    for (( ; colNr<=maxCols; colNr++ )); do
        printf '%s' $(( maxRows + 1 - rowNr ))
    done
    printf '\n'

done
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
         6
        55
      4444
    333333
  22222222
1111111111
```

I've no idea, of course, if you actually WANT to change from 1 to 2 chars at a time after the 2nd row or based on some percentage of rows printed or anything else so I used lots of meaningful variable names so you can see the idea and hopefully tweak it to do whatever it is you really want to do.